# IIS 10 is adding an unknown password to PDFs served via ISAPI web service

Tags: delphi, pdf, iis, indy, isapi

I have a web service written in Delphi. One of its functions is to return PDF documents that it has generated.

The exact same code-base can be built as an EXE (no IIS required) and as an ISAPI DLL.

*When the ISAPI DLL is loaded on to IIS 10, it appears to automatically add a password to the PDF content in the response*, when I browse to the link in Chrome I get:

**Password required**

**This document is password protected. Please enter a password.**

I am unable to open the document, as I do not know what password it has added.

The stand-alone web service that does not rely on IIS works perfectly.

When I scrutinise the response with Postman, it shows me that the IIS service's response is about 100 KB larger than the PDF that works okay. When I download the response and try to open the IIS PDF file with Adobe, I am still asked for a password, and the document won't open.

Any ideas how I can stop IIS altering the content of my response when Content-Type is application/pdf?

Comment: Can you debug that ISAPI to learn what exactly it does on the PDF request/response process? IIS won't add passwords to PDF documents.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is some kind of minor corruption, which is just enough to scramble the password. I am having a problem serving up .jpg data as well. If I inspect the exact raw content, they are fairly similar.

I found this which sounds like it could be it, except the dates are all wrong for my problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2749660/fix-response-is-corrupted-when-you-configure-an-outgoing-rule-in-url-r

The fix came about in 2012, and my rewrite .dll is dated 2 days after this article was written in Sept 2018. I tried the patch, got error not installed

Comment: Looks like the corruption is some kind of content encoding issue, and that the Delphi EXE and the Delphi Isapi DLL handle things differently...

Comment: If you found the cause and solution, post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Thank you Lex, I think I am making progress now that I am not barking up the wrong tree. Will post full solution as soon as I have it

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem!

IIS does not do any auto-protection of the contents of a PDF file (thanks Lex!).

What was happening is the PDF binary data was going from one stream to another via a string. For some reason the IIS ASAPI DLL used a different default character set/encoding/code page, and altered some of the more obscure characters.

This was just enough to alter the password embedded in the PDF, without corrupting the file so mush that adobe no longer recognised it as a PDF.

My old faulty code (that worked in the EXE but not the ISAPI DLL):

```
Response.Content := LIdHTTP.Get(LURL, LResponseStream);
```

My working code:

```
LResponseStream := TMemoryStream.Create; //don't free yourself, indy will
LIdHTTP.Get(LURL, LResponseStream); //avoid any string encoding to avoid problem with jpg and pdf
Response.ContentType := LIdHTTP.Response.ContentType;   
LResponseStream.Position := 0; //NB if this is not done, then NO content gets returned in ISAPI dll!
Response.ContentStream := LResponseStream;
```

I was further flummoxed until I set the stream read position back to zero. Without that, the EXE worked fine, but the ISAPI DLL returned Content-Length zero, and no data.

Goes to show, you need to build your web service for IIS from the very beginning (which I am doing, but as you can see it STILL heavy going!)